# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token. where I am going wrong?

Tags: java, android, json, exception, retrofit

I saw many of stackOverflow answers but I am not getting any clue.
Please answer if you have any suggestion on this.
I have been trying from last evening.

I am trying to parse json response using retrofit.

Json response I am getting :

```
{"total_entries":3,"skip":0,"limit":100,"items":[{"_id":"583c2281a28f9a9e1a000071","created_at":"2016-11-28T12:26:41Z","last_message":"Hello Dhiren !","last_message_date_sent":1480589762,"last_message_user_id":21053802,"name":"Dhiren Parmar","occupants_ids":[21053802,21054743],"photo":null,"type":3,"updated_at":"2016-12-01T10:56:02Z","user_id":21054743,"xmpp_room_jid":null,"unread_messages_count":0},{"_id":"5841107aa28f9ac86c000031","created_at":"2016-12-02T06:11:06Z","last_message":null,"last_message_date_sent":null,"last_message_user_id":null,"name":"anmol","occupants_ids":[21053802,21155690],"photo":null,"type":3,"updated_at":"2016-12-02T06:11:06Z","user_id":21053802,"xmpp_room_jid":null,"unread_messages_count":0},{"_id":"584110b7a28f9a22eb000008","created_at":"2016-12-02T06:12:07Z","last_message":null,"last_message_date_sent":null,"last_message_user_id":null,"name":"group chat with devi and heet","occupants_ids":[21053802,21062212,21155354],"photo":null,"type":2,"updated_at":"2016-12-02T06:12:07Z","user_id":21053802,"xmpp_room_jid":"49845_584110b7a28f9a22eb000008@muc.chat.quickblox.com","unread_messages_count":0}]}
```

My response model class :

```
public class DialogListResponse {
public final long total_entries;
public final long skip;
public final long limit;
public final List<Item> items;

@JsonCreator
public DialogListResponse(@JsonProperty("total_entries") long total_entries,
                          @JsonProperty("skip") long skip,
                          @JsonProperty("limit") long limit,
                          @JsonProperty("items") List<Item> items){
    this.total_entries = total_entries;
    this.skip = skip;
    this.limit = limit;
    this.items = items;
}

public static  class Item {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public  String _id;
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    public  String created_at;
    @JsonProperty("last_message")
    public  String last_message;
    @JsonProperty("last_message_date_sent")
    public  long last_message_date_sent;
    @JsonProperty("last_message_user_id")
    public  long last_message_user_id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public  String name;
    @JsonProperty("occupants_ids")
    public Set<Integer> occupants_ids;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    public  long type;
    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    public  String updated_at;
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    public  long user_id;
    @JsonProperty("unread_messages_count")
    public  long unread_messages_count;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public String getLast_message() {
        return last_message;
    }

    public void setLast_message(String last_message) {
        this.last_message = last_message;
    }

    public long getLast_message_user_id() {
        return last_message_user_id;
    }

    public void setLast_message_user_id(long last_message_user_id) {
        this.last_message_user_id = last_message_user_id;
    }

    public long getLast_message_date_sent() {
        return last_message_date_sent;
    }

    public void setLast_message_date_sent(long last_message_date_sent) {
        this.last_message_date_sent = last_message_date_sent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getOccupants_ids() {
        return occupants_ids;
    }

    public void setOccupants_ids(Set<Integer> occupants_ids) {
        this.occupants_ids = occupants_ids;
    }

    public long getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(long type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public long getUnread_messages_count() {
        return unread_messages_count;
    }

    public void setUnread_messages_count(long unread_messages_count) {
        this.unread_messages_count = unread_messages_count;
    }
}}
```

Retorfit portion that is responsible for pasring :

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(Utility.getJsonMapper()));


public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

Logcat error :
[image]

Comment: are you used Proguard? If yes please try disable Proguard

Comment: I have added proguard for release mode only, that I removed now.
yet no visible changes.

Comment: @DhirenParmar Show your full log

Comment: What is your error? Can you insert logs or similar of 'error' state? Exception?

Comment: @DhirenParmar Check Response json via POSTMAN because the log tells jsonarray at the position jsonobject available and use @ and menon my name while you comment